# Closing a tab after server side script has executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little assistance.  I want to close a firefox tab after a classic asp script has executed which is run at specific times of the day automatically.

I have tried the following code without success:

```
<% ASP SCRIPT %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){window.close();}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks, neojakey

Comment: you can't close tabs/windows automatically. Only with the `window.close()` but you will be asked to confirm. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301780/javascript-code-to-close-tab-that-works-in-ie-firefox-and-chrome). It doesn't seem possible.